# Is there any way to view whitespace in the query editor for SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ide, whitespace, ssms

I have it enabled in Visual Studio 2008, but I'd really like to enable this feature in SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Express. Does anyone know if its possible? Maybe in a later version?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I meant specifically in the text/query editor.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean in the query window, results window, etc.? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Simon Chadwick: Sorry, I meant the query/text editor. Need? No need. Just wanted to customize the look and feel, similar to how I have my VS 2008 editor. For example, you can customize the fonts and colors ... 'view whitespace' is another nice little feature.
I don't think its possible, but there's plenty of hidden options buried in there so I thought someone on StackOverflow might know how to do it.
...the answer can also be "No."

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In case you still need to know how to do this.

Edit the Registry Key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`:

```
Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\xx\Tools\Shell\Text Editor\Visible Whitespace
```

**Where xx is the version you have (90 is 2005, 100 is 2008)**

And set it to 1 to show. Or for SQL Server 2012 and up client tools it is also in `HKCU`:

```
Software\Microsoft\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\v\Text Editor\Visible Whitespace
```

where *v* in SQL Server 2012 is `11.0` and in SQL Server 2014 is `12.0`.

Comment: I'm shocked and horrified that it takes a registry setting to change visibility of white space since the color of white space is so easy to set in the options. But you're right, so +1 to you sir.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found the option for SQL 2012 under: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio \11.0\TextEditor -> Visible Whitespace

Comment: Can we also do the same for Results Grid View?

Comment: For anyone shocked as @BernhardHofmann, keep scroling, in new versions it can be done with a key combination now! :D

Answer (score 32):

Try doing **Ctrl R, Ctrl W** (or activate from menu *Edit > Advanced > View White Space*).

This is **Edit.ViewWhiteSpace** command (you can see this in Tools>Options>Keyboard) and should be assigned to that keyboard combination. You can in fact also type this command in Command Window (**Ctrl+Alt+A**).

This worked for me with Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60.

Comment: I found that this also exists under Edit > Advanced > View White Space in version 11.0.2100.60.

Answer (score 25):

Starting in SSMS 2012 this is available in  *Edit* > *Advanced* > *View White Space*

Answer (score 3):

SSMS (2005, I don't know about 2008) does not provide this functionality.

However, you could use a font that uses visible glyphs for spaces and tabs, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc1Pw.jpg

I used a free font editor called [Type Light](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/win/10897323) to make a copy of an existing font, with a visible space glyph.

I know it's a hack, but where there's a will there's usually a way...

Comment: @Simon Chadwick Yeah, I figured it didn't have the functionality, but I just wanted someone to confirm it for me (couldn't find it anywhere on Google!) At any rate, that's a clever workaround -- I think I'll give it a shot!