# How to see White Spaces in the Result Grid of my SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, whitespace

I would like to see white spaces in the result grid als default. (Just like in Word)
I am not searching for a SQL Workaround to see it in a specific query. 
Changing fonts did not work as i was not able to Change fonts in the results.

Comment: SQL doesn't work like word. If there's no data in a row it won't return any results. Try not to think of SSMS as a presentation layer, it really isn't, if you want this then you'd be better doing it outside of SSMS

Comment: actually you can do it, try the answers in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760124/is-there-any-way-to-view-whitespace-in-the-query-editor-for-sql-server-managemen I cannot verify it since i have an express SSMS

Comment: In the query Editor it worked like it is stated in the post "In case you still need to know how to do this.

Edit the Registry Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\xx\Tools\Shell\Text Editor\Visible Whitespace
"

Comment: @B3stie i tried to navigate also in my registry it is not present, is your SSMS enterprise edition? :)

Comment: Yes, it is Enterprise.