# Is there a way to view whitespace in SQL Server Management Studio 2016?

Tags: ssms, whitespace, ssms-2016

It doesn't look to me like there's any menu option which enables whitespace to be viewed in the text editor.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760124/is-there-any-way-to-view-whitespace-in-the-query-editor-for-sql-server-managemen), however this is referring to SSMS Express 2005 . An answer to this question shows how whitespace viewing can be enabled by editing registry values. However, i don't have that path specified in my registry. (I've checked each dir in the SQL Server registry and can't find a 'Visible Whitespace' entry)

I am using `SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (v 13.0.15500.91)`

Surely there must be a way to achieve this. It's not really required but I would like my settings to match my other versions of SSMS.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The option is under: Edit > Advanced > View White Space

Comment: It seems like there's no way to add this option to a Toolbar... I can't find it anywhere in the list of commands you can custom-add.

Comment: @Wouter - It's now in newer versions of SSMS. I have it in SSMS 18 (v15.0.18410.0); David Bippes' answer below details how to set it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add this to a toolbar:

- In the Customize Toolbar window, click "Add Command"
- Click "Edit" in the Categories list
- Choose "Toggle Visual Space" in the Commands list
- Click "OK"
- Move the button where you want it, then click "Close"

Comment: @Wouter does this help?