# Remove special characters in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) query editor

Tags: sql, ssms

In SSMS query editor, I see these arrows,dots and square whereever I hit TAB,SPACE and ENTER keys respectively. I have attached the image to be more clear in my question. Can anyone please suggest me a way to remove this and get back to the normal view in sql server?
Sorry if this is a repeat question as I am not aware of the appropriate term to search for these 
[special characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwLxV.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters don't actually exist in your code - they're indicators of whitespace. The arrows represent tabs, the dots spaces.

However, this is not a "native" SSMS configuration option. It's not an option you can enable through SSMS's menus or settings dialog. You *may* have it switched on via a [registry setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760124/is-there-any-way-to-view-whitespace-in-the-query-editor-for-sql-server-managemen), or perhaps you have an third-party add-in/plugin installed which is showing it. If that's the case, you'll have to check the options of that add-in.

Answer (score 2):

While your cursor is in the edit window, open menu `Edit/Advanced/View White Space` - this option toggles showing white-space characters (tabs, spaces, etc.) as shown in your image.

Comment: Thanksssss!! I was crazy with that, ha ha